# A function that sorts between equal number of a value in true or false

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, sorting

I am currently struggling with making a function that checks for numbers in a 4x4 table, in right and wrong systematically.

I have the function:
`game([ ["1","2","1","2"], ["2","1","1","2"], ["2","2","1","1"], ["1","1","2","2"]])`

What i am trying to do, is to make sure, that it checks if there is an equal number of 1's and 2's in each row and column and loads the message "true" if there is, and "false" if there is not

Comment: You will have only `1` & `2`?

Comment: the value doesnt matter, as long as there is only two. But 1 and 2 would be great yes

Comment: I hope it makes sense, its hard to describe in english :/

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) (and get a badge). Your question lacks any attempt at solving this problem on your own. The idea is for you to try to get something to work and then come here with specific problems you are unable to resolve. Taking the tour and reading about [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in the help center will provide all the information you need.

Comment: Sorry, i just thought my attempts would confuse more

Comment: @Scripter13, many answers, you only have to chose one  :)

Comment: @IsraGab your code is so clean :D

Answer (score 1):

I'll do the following.
First declare 2 object like this:

```js
var rows= {1:[], 2: []};
var columns= {1:[], 2: []};
// it will count how many of each number you have in rows and in columns
```

Then run over the arrays to count each value:

```js
data.forEach((arr, idx) => {
  rows[1][idx] = 0;
  rows[2][idx] = 0;
  arr.forEach((value, _idx) =>{
   if(!columns[value][_idx]){
    columns[value][_idx] = 0;
    }
    columns[value][_idx] += 1;
    rows[value][idx] +=1;
  });
})
```

Then you will have to compare values from `rows[1]` and `rows[2]` for the rows and `columns[1]` and `columns[2]` for the columns

```js
rows[1].forEach((val, idx) => console.log(val === rows[2][idx]));
columns[1].forEach((val, idx) => console.log(val === columns[2][idx]));
```

Answer (score 1):

A Nested loop goes through the array sequentially one row after the other. However, if you change the order of the indices (i and j), the traversal will be column-wise. Hence in one nested loop, you can traverse row-wise and column-wise.

```js
function game(arr) {

    let oneRow = 0; //calculates ones in a row
    let oneCol = 0; //calculates ones in a col
    let twoRow = 0; //calculates twos in a row
    let twoCol = 0; //calculates twos in a col
    
    let dim = arr.length;

    for (i = 0; i < dim; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < dim; j++) {
            if (arr[i][j] == '1') oneRow++;
            else twoRow++;
            if (arr[j][i] == '1') oneCol++;
            else twoCol++;
        }

        if (oneRow === twoRow && oneCol === twoCol) {
            oneRow = oneCol = twoRow = twoCol = 0;
            continue;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true
}

console.log(
  game([["1", "2", "1", "2"],
        ["2", "1", "1", "2"],
        ["2", "2", "1", "1"],
        ["1", "1", "2", "2"],
       ])
);
```

Comment: Hardcoding the magic number `4` in `i < 4` and `j < 4` makes this a brittle solution (only works for exactly 4x4 tables). It'd be preferable to use `arr.length`, which allows any size of square table.

Answer (score 0):

First, we will create a transpose of our given matrix, now we can traverse and check the numbers of 1's and 2's from both rows and columns very easily.

Next, we just filter the rows and columns based on 1's and 2's and see if the number of 1 and 2 are the same, if not, then immediately return `false` and if our game array satisfy our condition of equal 1's and 2's, return `true`

```js
function game(gameArray) {
  let transpose = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < gameArray.length; i++) {
    let temp = [];
    for (let j = 0; j < gameArray.length; j++) {
      temp.push(gameArray[j][i]);
    }
    transpose.push(temp);
  }

  console.table(gameArray);
  console.table(transpose);

  for (let i = 0; i < gameArray.length; i++) {
    aArrOne = gameArray[i].filter((elem) => elem === "1").length;
    aArrTwo = gameArray[i].filter((elem) => elem === "2").length;
    tArrOne = transpose[i].filter((elem) => elem === "1").length;
    tArrTwo = transpose[i].filter((elem) => elem === "2").length;

    if (aArrOne !== aArrTwo || tArrOne !== tArrTwo) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  return true;
}

console.log(
  game([
    ["1", "2", "1", "2"],
    ["2", "1", "1", "2"],
    ["2", "2", "1", "1"],
    ["1", "1", "2", "2"],
  ])
);
```

Comment: One note: this transposition function will only work for "square" tables (equal number of rows & cols). While that's how the problem was originally described, this could trip you up if you had a non-square input table.

Answer (score 0):

**While the original problem describes a square table (equal number of columns and rows) and only two possible values, I thought it'd be interesting to solve this for square and non-square tables, and an unlimited number of unique values.**

This solution "fails fast": as soon as we find a single row or column with unequal values, we return `"false"` and stop iterating over rows/columns. If we find an unequal-value row, we don't even need to do the extra computational work of pivoting the table and checking columns.

```js
/*

At each index of the row, check if there's a corresponding key ("column") in the map.

If there is, push this value into that "column".
If there's not, create the "column" for this row index and set its first value to this value.

Finally, convert the Map back to the original nested-Array structure
with some clever shorthand: brackets around the spread operator.

*/

function pivot(table) {
  console.log('pivoting table!')
  const rotated = new Map()
  for (row of table) {
    row.forEach((v, i) => rotated.get(i) ? rotated.get(i).push(v) : rotated.set(i, [v]))
  }
  return [...rotated.values()]
}


/*

For each element in the array, check to see if we've "seen" the value yet.

If yes, increase the count in the map for this value
If no, create a new key in the map for this value, and start counting.

After collecting counts, make a Set of the counts, which will keep only unique values.

If all the element counts are equal, this Set's size will be 1.
If all the element counts weren't equal, the Set will be larger than 1.

*/

function areElementCountsUnequal(arr) {
  const counts = new Map()
  arr.forEach(v => counts.get(v) ? counts.set(v, counts.get(v) + 1) : counts.set(v, 1))
  const uniqueElementCounts = new Set([...counts.values()])
  return uniqueElementCounts.size !== 1
}


function game(table) {
  for (row of table) {
    if (areElementCountsUnequal(row)) {
      console.log(`row unequal: ${row}`)
      return 'false'
    }
  }

  const tablePivoted = pivot(table)
  for (col of tablePivoted) {
    if (areElementCountsUnequal(col)) {
      console.log(`col unequal: ${col}`)
      return 'false'
    }
  }
     
  // we must not have found any unequal ones!
  return 'true'
}


const inputTable1 = [
  ["1","2","1","2"],
  ["2","1","1","2"],
  ["2","2","1","1"],
  ["1","1","2","2"]
]

const result1 = game(inputTable1)
console.log(result1)

console.log('---- next game ----')

const inputTable2 = [
  ["1","3","1","2","3","2"],
  ["2","1","1","2","3","2"],
  ["2","2","1","1","1","2"],
  ["1","1","2","2","1","2"]
]

const result2 = game(inputTable2)
console.log(result2)
```